# Firebase Auth API error even after deploying it successfully

Tags: firebase-authentication, github-actions, firebase-hosting

I have created a website using firebase and React. I have hosted it using firebase and setup automatic build using GitHub whenever a PR is merged. But the build is failing everytime which make my website blank and throws Auth error in the console.
I get this error on GitHub in my notification: Deploy to firebase hosting on merge workflow run failed for main branch

I have tried almost everything. I even run firebase init again and this time selected to host everytime manually but it is still not working.
Whenever I deploy it for my terminal it works perfect but not from GitHub.
I think I am somewhere lagging in setting it up using GitHub like I think I don't know how to setup secrets and yaml file.
Can anyone please help me with this.